# How to determine if one template argument are null?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using this template to print different types of data to the console, however, if one argument is `NULL` it generates an exception.

How I can add verification to avoid getting an exception?

I tried adding:

```
 if (sizeof...(args) == 0)
    return;
```

But it still reads `NULL` values.

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void doPrint(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    if (sizeof...(args) == 0)
        return;

    std::wostringstream out;

    out << std::forward<Arg>(arg);

    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander {
        0, (void(out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...
    };

    OutputDebugString(out.str().c_str());
    std::cout << out.str().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

How to reproduce the exception:

```
    BSTR name = NULL;
    doPrint("name: ", name);
```

Comment: What is `BSTR`?

Comment: `typedef /* [wire_marshal] */ OLECHAR *BSTR;` its a data type used on the UIAutomation lib.

Comment: @Evg Microsoft for char pointer I guess

Comment: `if (sizeof...(args) == 0)` does not do what you think it does. If the problem is `arg` being NULL, what does checking if the subsequent parameter pack is empty will have to do with it? Was this part of some code that came back from a Google search, for whatever search keywords were used, and you tried copy/pasting it without understanding what this actually does, in C++? What is the reason for that weird cast, the one that employs the `using` keyword is supposed to do?

Comment: The size of NULL is 8 bytes :) https://godbolt.org/z/95ojbKdc1

Comment: @MadFred: Unless it's not. You can't assume the size on one implementation is the size on all. Besides, that's not the subject of this question.

Comment: @mad A `BSTR` isn't *just* a pointer to any old character array. It represents a length-prefixed, zero-terminated wide character string with a few additional [semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics) (e.g. a null pointer and a pointer to a string of length 0 must compare equal). It's used throughout COM as the standard string type, superseded by `HSTRING` in the Windows Runtime.

Comment: `NULL` is just an alias for `0`, so its size is `sizeof(int)`. `nullptr` is a `nullptr_t` which is an implementation-defined type. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is that `operator <<` taking `BSTR` expects non-null pointer.

```
BSTR name = nullptr;
out << name; // Wrong expect non-null pointer
```

You might create overload for custom display and handling special case:

```
template <typename T>
std::wostream& doPrintImpl(std::wostream& out, const T& arg)
{
    return out << arg;
}

std::wostream& doPrintImpl(std::wostream& out, const BSTR arg)
{
    return out << (arg == nullptr ? L"NULL" : arg);
}


template <typename... Args>
void doPrint(const Args&... args)
{
    std::wostringstream out;

    auto print = [&](const auto& arg){
        doPrintImpl(out, arg);
        out << std::left << std::setw(20);
    };

    using expander = int[];
    (void)expander { 0, (print(args), 0)... }; // equivalent of C++17 (print(args), ...); 

    OutputDebugString(out.str().c_str());
    std::cout << out.str().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I dont understand why people think they are forced to take in rvalue references all the time.

Comment: `'std::ostream &doPrintImpl(std::ostream &,const BSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::wostringstream' to 'std::ostream &'`

Comment: @Katia: Trivial typo. Should be `std::wostream`. the w fell off.

Comment: Typo should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

First:

```cpp
if (sizeof...(args) == 0)
```

This only check how many arguments you have. It doesn't do anything about what they actually are.

Instead you need to actually check if each arguments are `nullptr`. Naturally, you want something like:

```cpp
args != nullptr
    ? out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)
    : out
```

This would work if all `args` are meant to be pointer types. However, it will fail if you pass in anything else, since `operator!=` isn't defined between value types and `std::nullptr_t`.

Instead, you could write a set of helper functions `isNullptr`, that will do either return false if you pass in a value type, or check if they are `nullptr` if you pass in a pointer type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool isNullptr(T* ptr)
{
    return !ptr;
}

template <typename T>
bool isNullptr(T)
{
    return false;
}
```

Now, you can change your previous statement to:

```cpp
!isNullptr(args)
    ? out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args)
    : out
```

And you can put it in your expander:

```cpp
(void)expander {((!isNullptr(args) ? out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args) : out), 0)...};
```

Or for c++17 or later:

```cpp
((!isNullptr(args) ? out << std::left << std::setw(20) << std::forward<Args>(args) : out), ...);
```

Comment: could you provide a working example for c++17 or later? i don't understand how to merge all these snippets you post

Comment: @Daniela For C++17 and later, the last snippet is all you need within the `doPrint` function. You also need the two `isNullptr` free functions to determine if they are not `nullptr`.